# Symfony 2 Variable Entity Naming

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I feel like this shouldn't be to hard, but try as I might, I keep getting errors.

What I'm wanting to do, is to have a single "add" function that will handle the basic functionality of adding records to any / all tables.  Basically, the post data will contain the table name, as well as the fields / values to be inserted.  The controller itself, confirms the user has access to do these things, and then verifies the fields are valid, before creating a new instance of the entity, that's where things go haywire:

```
$entityName = 'Products';
$row = new $entityName(); //doesn't work
$row new Products(); //works
```

I haven't found a way or any examples of creating a new entity using the Entity Manager, or else that might work, because i've created functions using EM to do queries, updates, and deletes, but I just can't get this to work with the add functions.

Comment: I am not sure if symfony2 is capable of this. You are trying to write your own code dinamically, you could try with php create a new file, write all the php class there and save it, and then execute with php app/console doctrine:schema:update... I am very doubtfull of the success though.

Comment: Drop the parens.  $row = new $entityName;  If that does not work then post the error message.  Something else is going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1.** Your problem is almost certainly namespacing (see below). Try this instead:

```
$entityName = 'My\Bundle\Entity\Products';
$row = new $entityName();
```

Should work. ;)

**2.** If you want to create new instances using an EntityManager, try this:

```
$entityName = 'My\Bundle\Entity\Products';
$row = $em->getClassMetadata($entityName)->newInstance();
```

...assuming `$em` is your EntityManager. :-)

**3.** To "prove" that your problem is namespacing, try this in a plain .php file that you run from the command line:

```
namespace Foo;
class Test {}

$class1 = 'Foo\Test';
$class2 = 'Test';

$x = new Test();    // Will work
$y = new $class1(); // Will work
$z = new $class2(); // Will trigger "Class 'Test' not found" fatal error
```

Comment: I think the problem was a combination of my entity being a variable and having to escape my slashes.  It works now like this $entity_name = 'Some\\bundle\\entity\\' . $entity;  $row = new $entity_name();  Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

- Try with **"Products"** instead of **'Products'**
- I suppose that your entity Products has a namespace, it is required (even if you declared an use statement). So try with "My\Bundle\Entity\Products".

Comment: I've tried using the namespace to no avail.  Again new Products(); works, but new $entityName doesn't.

Comment: I've edited my answer, I wasn't clear, try with double quotes instead of simple quotes